# how to make a chart on country map by using python

Tags: python, excel

I want to make a chart on any country's map by using python. For example: To make a record of Covid-19 infected or death toll of a country on that country map, what type of module or how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You really should review how to ask questions on SO                            https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask                                                                                    Posting what you have tried so far(the code). Would help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need a data set as far as I understand. Data you can use for corona virus,

[Corona virus data set](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data)

Download the csv files here.
Later,

With phyton, you can learn how to transfer to excel.

[csv to excel](https://datatofish.com/csv-to-excel-python/)

To make a graphic, to examine here.

[pyhton chart](https://python-graph-gallery.com/193-annotate-matplotlib-chart/)

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib and Seaborn can help you with necessarily this.